# What is the command line to start a gadget in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, desktop-gadget

I need to make sure that some Windows 7 gadget is running at a specific time of day (10am) for an user.

Surely, I can start it once and let it run forever, but the user may accidentally or intentionally close the gadget, which breaks the system.

To avoid this situation, I'm proposing the solution of creating a task in the Task Scheduler to start the gadget every day at, say, 9:55am. The problem is that, AFAIK, activating gadgets can only be done through the Windows GUI, so here goes my question:

Is it possible to start a gadget using a command line? If so, how?

Comment: What if the user hides desktop gadgets altogether?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/328357f2-5aa7-4772-b9d0-4713a3945c07/run-a-sidebar-gadget-upon-start-up-and-possibly-align-to-a-specific-grid?forum=sidebargadfetdevelopment

Comment: @and31415, this is more to prevent mistakes than anything else. If the user chooses to hide or close the gadgets, s/he will be accounted for that.

Comment: @MDMoore313, thanks for the link. I'll investigate the solution presented there.